# Is there a way to know how much spot capacity there is in particular availability zones? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to launch a spot x1.32xlarge in US West (Oregon), to do some processing of large spatial data files.  The pricing history is very stable:
[image]

But I get `capacity-not-availabe`.  In fact, this happens fairly frequently with big instances of various sorts.  My code is fairly portable, so I could start this up in another region.  Before I do so, can I look at that region somehow to figure out whether I'll get a `capacity-not-available` delay?

I understand that my instance will start up eventually, but I use spot basically like on-demand instances with cheaper price traded for flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to discover the available spot pool capacity in a region or an availability zone.  (The exception is when the market price is pegged to the max, which seems to be a good sign that no spot capacity exists at all).

Since the changes to the algorithm in November, 2017, the prices no longer track demand as aggressively as they formerly did, so even though a trend upwards implies higher demand and a trend downwards implies lower demand, a flat line below on-demand does not seem to send a clear signal.  It is possible, now, to have a spot instance terminate due to capacity and restart a few minutes later, without an actual change in the price, which I attribute to on-demand instances pulling capacity out of the spot pool, but that is speculation.  (I've seen this only on some large instance types).

In any event, the actual pool capacity and availability of spot instances are not externally accessible.